# In a Maven multi-module project how to generate only one .classpath and .project for the whole project including modules?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, multi-module

I'm trying to create a Maven Multi-module project with only one .classpath and .project and .settings for the whole project including modules but every time the mvn eclipse:eclipse is executed it generates a .classpath, .project and a .settings directory for the parent project and for each subproject. What i want is to have a structure like this :

For example:

The name of the parent project is:

- root-parent-project

The modules (subprojects) are :

- transverse
- service
- transport
- client
- webapp

In the **Package Explorer** view:

+- root-parent-project/

```
        +-transverse/src/main/java
        +-service/src/main/java
        +-service/src/main/resources
        +-service/src/test/java
        +-service/src/test/resources
        +-transport/src/main/java
        +-transport/src/main/java
        +-client/src/main/java
        +--client
        +--service          
        +--transport
        +--transverse   
        +--webapp
        +-pom.xml
```

In the **Navigator** view:

+- root-parent-project/

```
        +-.settings
                +- ...
        +-client/
            +-src
            +-target
            +-pom.xml
        +--service/ 
            +-src
            +-target
            +-pom.xml           
        +--transport/
            +-src
            +-target
            +-pom.xml           
        +--transverse/
            +-src
            +-target
            +-pom.xml           
        +--webapp/
            +-src
            +-target
            +-pom.xml
        +- .classpath
        +- .project
        +- pom.xml
```

I don't want Maven (m2eclipse) when executing mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate a .project file, .classpath file and .settings for every module.

I hope i have been clear enough :).

Thank you for your help.
Best regards.

Comment: First why don't you use m2e instead of *mvn eclipse:eclipse* furthermore it makes from my point of view no sense to have only a single .classpath etc. for modules which are separated in maven modules. What is the reason for going into this direction?

Comment: Hi, because i don't want Eclipse to consider every module as a separate prject. In fact, it's a way of organization. Thanks.

Comment: Than you can't do that with Eclipse nor with Maven and it does not make sense to combine projects which are intended to be separated based on the module structure.

Comment: thank you @khmarbaise, it seems to be logic what you said.